# How to frame steel studs parallel to concrete ceiling "joists"

Tags: drywall, studs

One of the drywall I need to hang runs parallel to the joists (concrete joists and slab above it), and I'm at lost on how to affix the upper tracks which would be between two joists.

I've seen this problem address with wooden joists and studs, but it is kind of different problem when using steel studs and concrete joists.

Comment: A photo might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a picture, I am guessing you want to frame a wall out of steel studs and you are asking how to fasten the track between the concrete beams. The only way to do this is to either run your wall all the way up to the slab, or to span the concrete beams perpendicular with a piece of track or stud. Just cut tongues on either side of the track and install it legs up with a shutgun or rotohammer every four feet. Once you have these up you can secure your top track to this. You won't need to do this at either end of the track since the end stud, which should be attached to the wall will hold the track.

Comment: That is exactly the case, I got an answer about that in a forum and forgot to update it here. Have an approved answer.